# Websocket error when using nginx with Streamlit

Tags: nginx, streamlit

I have a a Streamlit application running in a container listening on port 8505.
I'm using nginx with this configuration

```
worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
    
        server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.example.com;
    location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8505;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
    }
    }
```

My hosts file maps `app1.example.com` to `127.0.0.1`.
When directing chrome to `http://app1.example.com/` the main page of the streamlit app starts to load, but I get the following error
`main.dccfd6b5.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'ws://app2.example.com/_stcore/stream' failed: main.dccfd6b5.js:2 WebsocketConnection WebSocket onerror`

Any idea how to configure nginx to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, should add websocket config.

```
        location /_stcore/stream {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/_stcore/stream;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
```

see this [link](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/websocketconnection-websocket-onerror/46298)